# The prefab asset from the assetstore is not imported correctly (3d model with animation)

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I am importing a purchased asset from an assetstore.  Animated cat model.  However, all prefabs are assembled incorrectly at once, the components are not in their places.  Please tell me what could be the problem.  In the attachment, the screen on the left is what it is, on the right - just the model as it should look. Support said they were correct.  I have the same problem on two different computers.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOkFD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the defects in the bones. Root bone may not be defined, but if after import; No change any option or just resize it. Undoubtedly the problem is for modeling.